# mongodb get list of fields in all collections by using map reduce job

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce

I have list of collection names in mongo database.I need  a script to get all fileds names in each collections by passing collection name as argument by using map reduce job in mongo database.

This is what I have so far:

```
mr = db.runCommand({
    "mapreduce" : "collectionname",
    "map" : function() { for (var key in this) { emit(key, null); } },
    "reduce" : function(key, stuff) { return null; },
    "out": "collectioname" + "_keys"
})
```

or in one line for executing it in the mongo shell:

`mr = db.runCommand({
        "mapreduce" : "collectionname",
        "map" : function() { for (var key in this) { emit(key, null); } },
        "reduce" : function(key, stuff) { return null; },
        "out": "collectioname" + "_keys"
    })`

This command was used to get list of fields in the collection. But this one is working only on primary one. I need to loop it (get all fields in each collection in the database). Thanks a lot.

Comment: We are not under your command. show us what you've got so far and we'll try to help you.

Comment: mr = db.runCommand({
  "mapreduce" : "collectionname",
  "map" : function() {
    for (var key in this) { emit(key, null); }
  },
  "reduce" : function(key, stuff) { return null; }, 
  "out": "collectioname" + "_keys"
})
 this is the command i have to used to get list of fields in the collection .But this one is working only on primary one.I need to loop it get all  fields in each collection in the database

Comment: This question has been answered quite a few times, infact I have answered this question about 3 times myself, you might wanna look at: https://github.com/variety/variety

Comment: How to run this code if host have username pwd and port values.i have tried as below on copied the code variety.js from here.But below command returns error.MongoDB shell version: 2.0-A3
connecting to: ma-ireconm-ldb02.corp.apple.com:10901/admin
Tue Jul 30 21:50:48 SyntaxError: syntax error (shell eval):1 mongo -u $usernames -p $PWD  $HOST:$PORT/admin --eval "db = db.getSiblingDB('database')","var collection = 'collectioname'"  variety.js

Comment: can you please format your code snippets correctly ? This is aweful

Answer (score 0):

The for loop you are looking for is:

```
var allCollections = db.getCollectionNames();

for (var i = 0; i < allCollections.length; ++i) {
     var collectioname = allCollections[i];
     // now do your map reduce for one collection here
     // there are the merge or reduce options for the output collection
     // in case you want to gather everything in one collection instead of:
     // collectioname + '_keys'
}
```

save this in a `script.js`

Then run it:

```
 mongo myDb script.js
```

or write it in one line and execute it the mongo shell:

`var allCollections = db.getCollectionNames(); for (var i = 0; i < allCollections.length; ++i) { var collectioname = allCollections[i]; if (collectioname === 'system.indexes') continue; db.runCommand({ "mapreduce" : collectioname, "map" : function() { for (var key in this) { emit(key, null); } }, "reduce" : function(key, stuff) { return null; }, "out": collectioname + "_keys" }) }`

But, please go thoroughly over the [mapReduce](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/mapReduce/#dbcmd.mapReduce) page and run **ALL** the examples there. This should make it clear how to use the `emit` function to have proper results at the end. You currently emit a `null` for a certain key. There and the return of the reduce are the places where you should use some data and aggregate the values you want (for example the collection name, which would be a constant being passed through).

Comment: Hi 
Gabriel Petrovay ,thanks for your replay .I am new to mongodb.I want to how to write  map reduce inside the loop and get all collections keys inside the DB and load into temp collection with collection  name and keys in the output.Thanks alot

Comment: And your question is. What you describe is what you see above: the `for` loop and you just have to place your map reduce inside. What does not work?

Comment: can please verify this code var allCollections = db.getCollectionNames();

for (var i = 0; i < allCollections.length; ++i) {var collectioname = allCollections[i];},
        {"map" : function() {
    for (var key in this) { emit(key, null); }
  },
  "reduce" : function(key, stuff) { return null; }, 
  "out": "collectioname" + "_keys"}

Comment: var allCollections = db.getCollectionNames();
rs_aissii4t_shard_1it:PRIMARY> for (var i = 0; i < allCollections.length; ++i) {var collectioname = allCollections[i]}
rs_aissii4t_shard_1it:PRIMARY> map: function() {for (var key in this) { emit(key, null); }
... ,
... reduce : function(key, stuff) { return null; }
... out: "collectioname" + "_keys"}
Wed Jul 31 17:03:34 SyntaxError: syntax error (shell):2 can you please help me to fix this syntax error.

Comment: I've added the one liner to my Answer above that is working for me. I filtered `system.indexes` out because: 1. it throws an error when you want to mapreduce it as well 2. you are probably not interested in its content since it is not user data

Comment: var allCollections = db.getCollectionNames(); for (var i = 0; i < allCollections.length; ++i) { var collectioname = allCollections[i]; if (collectioname === 'system.indexes') continue; db.runCommand({ "mapreduce" : collectioname, "map" : function() { for (var key in this) { emit(key, null); } }, "reduce" : function(key, stuff) { return null; }, "out": { merge: "mongotest"+"_keys"} }) }
I have modified the as pasted above and working good to get all the keys in the collection .but i want to store collection name also in the output of the map reduce.{ "datadisccoll" : "_id", "value" : null }

Comment: I extended my answer with some hints.